# How to print a docx file in reverse order in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, ms-word

I'm coding a Wpf application to print docx files. I can normally print it. This my code:

```
var info = new Process();
info.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(filePath) //in this pass the file path
{
    UseShellExecute = true
};
info.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";
info.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
info.Start();
info.WaitForExit();
info.Dispose();
```

But now, I want to print pages in this docx file by **reverse order**. First I wonder how can I use **AddCoreProperty** in DOCX package, but i don't find anyway to use it to print reverse order. I searched but could find any helpful information. Maybe by another solution, all useful with me.

Comment: If you were using the Interop, it would be a property of the Word object library: `Application.Options.PrintReverse = true;` This setting is specific for the Word UI and is not document-specific - the information cannot be stored in a document, so working with the docx cannot help. Unless you can get at the *printer* properties and make the change as the job spools, I don't think this can be done via a Process.

Comment: Anyway, thank @CindyMeister

Comment: @CindyMeister, if i use Process like i was, I can't print in reverse order, right?

Comment: If i use Interop, I must set up all require version to run appropriate files. I wonder it is right? If not, can you show me how to config in vs2019 to run all file without setting all corresponding Office

Comment: To your first comment: I don't know, except that it cannot be done via Word. There may well be printer APIs that C# can work with that can change the setting for the *printer, itself*.

Comment: To the second comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but I'll try. Word, itself, can open all versions of Word documents. The .NET-COM interop *could* have problems with the version of the Word software installed on a machine. The standard way to work around this is to set "Embed interop types" to TRUE in the project. There's also the option of working with "PInvoke", which is version-independent. Research those two topics to see if that helps.